# Facebook access api

Tags: facebook

Trying to get a token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived , but as can be seen from the returned result, the lifetime of the token is unchanged and ends on the same date. It turns out that on the expiration date of the token, I will not be able to generate a new one via the api, since the existing one will already be invalid. So you will have to do it only through your personal account?

used the documentation